# TextView is not showing on the gui in java in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple gui for an android app using java and xml.
But, the Textedit is showing on the TextView and therefore, the TextView is not showing. Here is my xml code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hello Chenura"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/simpleEditText"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#0099FF"
        android:text="Click to say 'welcome'"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I changed the layout linear to relative, but nothing happened.

Here's the screenshot of thr gui,
[Gui of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOnnv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!--Change fill_parent to wrap_content-->
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hello Chenura"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/simpleEditText"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_hello" <!--Position relative to TextView-->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#0099FF"
        android:text="Click to say 'welcome'"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to add `android:layout_below="@id/txt_hello"` to the EditText in order to position it relative to the TextView. You also need to add `wrap_content` in place of `fill_parent` because `fill_parent` makes the TextView cover the whole screen, hiding the other widgets.

Answer (score 0):

In Relative layout, you need to specify the position of the view relative to other views like layout_below, layout_above etc., you have not specified anything. That's why the 2 views are overlapping.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Hello Chenura"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/simpleEditText"
    android:layout_below="@id/txt_hello"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#0099FF"
    android:text="Click to say 'welcome'"/>
```

Adding android:layout_below="@id/txt_hello" will take solve of your problem
Also, change android:layout_height of txt_hello to "wrap_content"